# remove quotes that occur other than pairs

Tags: regex, quotes, double-quotes

How to remove extra quotes which do not occur in pair.
Suppose,

```
title:"no spacing before" and text breaks "
title:"no spacing before" and text breaks " after this
```

I need to the output as follows:

```
title:"no spacing before" and text breaks
title:"no spacing before" and text breaks after this
```

Comment: If you want to get real help, please update your question with 1) programming language, 2) your code, 3) what is wrong with your code/what you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
(".*?")|"
```

With a replacement string:

```
\1
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/kL9eH5/1)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should work for multiple pairs of double quotes ("), and match the pairs group. To remove double quote not in pairs, replace the match with \1:

```
([^"]*(?:"[^"]+"[^"]*)+[^"]*)(["])?
```

The demo is [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/oX3rE8/4).